# tensorflow - why tf.FIFOueue and StaingArea cannot accelerate my input pipeline

Tags: tensorflow

Because of inefficiency of feed_dict， I want to use FIFOQueue and StagingArea to accelerate my input pipeline. So I use a python thread to feed numpy data to tf.FIFOQueue and the main thread dequeue tensors to train. The latency of copying data from python runtime to tensorflow runtime has been hide if queue is not empty.

My test model is a Alexnet model, here is the model code

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Model(object):

def __init__(self, num_classes=1000):

    self.num_classes = num_classes

def inference(self, images):
    network = tf.layers.conv2d(
            images, 64, [11, 11], 4, padding='VALID')
    network = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(network, [3, 3], 2)
    network = tf.layers.conv2d(network, 192, [5, 5]) 
    network = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(network, [3, 3], 2)
    network = tf.layers.conv2d(network, 384, [3, 3]) 
    network = tf.layers.conv2d(network, 384, [3, 3]) 
    network = tf.layers.conv2d(network, 256, [3, 3]) 
    network = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(network, [3, 3], 2)

    network = tf.layers.flatten(network)
    network = tf.layers.dense(
            network, 4096, tf.nn.relu,
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0))
    network = tf.layers.dropout(network, rate=0.5)
    network = tf.layers.dense(
            network, 4096, tf.nn.relu,
            kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0))
    network = tf.layers.dropout(network, rate=0.5)
    network = tf.layers.dense(network, self.num_classes)

    return network

def compute_loss(self, logits, labels):
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(
            logits=logits, labels=labels)
    return tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

def build_model(self, images, labels):
    logits = self.inference(images)
    return self.compute_loss(logits, labels)

def get_optimizer(self):
    return tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
```

First of all, I use fake data to build baseline performance benchmark, generate images and labels using tensorflow random operators on cpu and gpu device
respectively， and the performance should achieve the upper limit.

```
import os
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
import argparse
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from model import Model
import pdb

num_classes = 1000
height = 227
width = 227
channel = 3

def input_pipeline(batch_size, device="/cpu:0", use_feed_dict=False):
    with tf.device(device):
        shape = [batch_size, height, width, channel]
        if use_feed_dict:
            images = tf.placeholder(shape=shape, dtype=tf.float32)
            labels = tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.int32)
        else:
           images = tf.truncated_normal(
                    shape, dtype=tf.float32,
                    mean=127, stddev=60)
            images = tf.contrib.framework.local_variable(images)
            labels = tf.random_uniform(
                    [batch_size], minval=0, maxval=num_classes, dtype=tf.int32)

        return images, labels

def build_fetches(images, labels):
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        model = Model(num_classes)
        loss = model.build_model(images, labels)
        optimizer = model.get_optimizer()
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    return train_op

def get_numpy_batch(batch_size):
    shape = [batch_size, height, width, channel]
    batch_images = np.random.random(shape).astype(np.float32)
    batch_labels = np.random.rand(batch_size) * 1000
    batch_labels = batch_labels.astype(np.int32)

    return batch_images, batch_labels

def main(args, warmup_steps=10):
    images, labels = input_pipeline(args.batch_size, args.device, 
        args.use_feed_dict)
    fetches = build_fetches(images, labels)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

        if args.use_feed_dict:
            batch_images, batch_labels = get_numpy_batch(args.batch_size)
            feed_dict = {
                    images: batch_images,
                    labels: batch_labels,
            }
        else:
            feed_dict = None

        for _ in xrange(warmup_steps):
            sess.run(fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict)

        begin = time.time()
        for _ in xrange(args.steps):
            sess.run(fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        time_cost = time.time() - begin

        print "%s: after %d steps for test, result is %.2f ms (%.3f ms/step)" % (
            datetime.now(), args.steps, time_cost * 1000, time_cost * 1000 / args.steps)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--device", default="cpu")
    parser.add_argument("--steps", type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=256)
    parser.add_argument("--use_feed_dict", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.use_feed_dict:
        args.device = "cpu"185.489
    args.device = "/%s:0" % args.device

    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
    main(args)
```

With enviroments of GPU P40 and tensorflow verison 1.4.1, batch_size is set to 256, which means the size of batch data is 150MB

```
|--------------------- |------------------|
|    device/feed_dict  |     ms/steps     |
|--------------------- |------------------|
|          cpu         |      106.367     |
|--------------------- |------------------|
|          gpu         |      92.650      |
|--------------------- |------------------|
|       feed_dict      |      115.710     |
|--------------------- |------------------|
```

It seems that copy 150MB data from python runtime to tf runtime takes 11ms and transfer data from cpu to gpu takes 14ms.

Then I use FIFOQueue and StagingArea data to preftch data

```
batch_images = np.random.random(
        [256, 227, 227, 3]).astype(np.float32)
batch_labels = np.random.rand(256) * 1000
batch_labels = batch_labels.astype(np.int32)

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    images_plr = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 227, 227, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
    labels_plr = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)

    queue = tf.FIFOQueue(106, 
            dtypes=[images_plr.dtype.base_dtype, labels_plr.dtype.base_dtype])
    enqueue_op = queue.enqueue([images_plr, labels_plr])
    images, labels = queue.dequeue()
    images.set_shape(images_plr.get_shape())
    labels.set_shape(labels_plr.get_shape())

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    stage = StagingArea(
            dtypes=[images.dtype.base_dtype, labels.dtype.base_dtype], shapes=None)
    put_op = stage.put([images, labels])
    images, labels = stage.get()
    images.set_shape(images_plr.shape)
    labels.set_shape(labels_plr.shape)

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    model = Model(1000)
    loss = model.build_model(images, labels)
    opt = model.get_optimizer()
    fetches = opt.minimize(loss)

    fetches = tf.group(fetches, put_op)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print "prefetch 106 steps data to fifoqueue"
    for _ in range(106):
        sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={images_plr : batch_images, labels_plr: batch_labels})

    sess.run(put_op)

    for _ in range(5):
        sess.run(fetches, feed_dict=None)

    begin = time.time()
    for _ in range(100):
         sess.run(fetches, feed_dict=None)
    time_cost = time.time() - begin
    print "after 100 steps for testing, result is %.2f ms/step" % (
         time_cost * 1000 / 100)
```

The result performace is 113.669 ms/step, which is only a little better than feed_dict, but my goal is to hide the latency of fetching data from python runtime to gpu. What's wrong with my code ?